# How can I get the current URL and add it to other web URL from JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I need help. I want build link with JavaScript.
I want get the current full URL and combined it to the [Copyscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyscape) web. And output in `A` HTML tags together. 
Here is my failing code:

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<a target="_blank" href="[http://www.copyscape.com/?q="](http://www.copyscape.com/?q=%22) + document.URL; + ">Test Link</a>'>);
</script>

And I want results outputted and redirected to http://www.copyscape.com/?q=MYCURRENTURL if clicked on new page.

Comment: Output and redirect don't make sense together. When a redirect occurs all script in current page is gone. Overall objective could use a lot more detail. Is copyscape.com your site domain?

Comment: Take some time to read through [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript:

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
```

jQuery:

```
 var url =  $(location).attr('href');
```

So in your case:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var url =  $(location).attr('href');

document.write('<a target="_blank" href="http://www.copyscape.com/?q=' + url + '">Test Link</a>');
```

Source: *[jQuery Get Current Page URL](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-current-page-url/)*

Comment: But why not created A tags (html) it outputed blank page.

Comment: @DimasLanjaka Your question isn't explicit then. You asked how to get the url, it answers it. Edit your question to ask what you really want.

Comment: Nice worked for me. I forgotten include jquery from ajax.google apis